# Programmatically applying a tilt effect on a stackpanel

Tags: winrt-xaml

I'm creating the elements of my WinRT app page during runtime because the contents are needed to be dynamically created.

I'm looking at Callisto and Telerik controls/effects and both of them applies the tilt effect during design time (on xaml).

Is there a way to apply the said effect during runtime? When I create my stackpanel on code - behind.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing a custom user control, which is my last resort.